# Can moderators please migrate without reopening a question?

Tags: feature-request, migration, closed-questions, moderator-tools

I'm seeing this more frequently now that we have the review queues (even if the post is flagged for potential migration) and questions are getting closed more quickly without moderator intervention. If the appropriate target site isn't one of the ones in the list (meaning users can't vote to migrate there) or it gets closed for the wrong reason, I need to reopen the question then reclose with an off-topic reason and select the site for migration. Instead, moderators should be able to migrate a question closed for any reason directly to another site without reopening first.

Comment: I think a simpler approach to this would be to add a "reclose" option for moderators, which allows them to go through the close dialog as normal, and the system automatically reopens the question then closes it again as the moderator specifies all in one step. This would also be helpful to moderators in those situations where a duplicate could be used instead of another close reason. But in the end, is it really *that* difficult to reopen it again first? It takes literally one second.